# Call function when user hits enter with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-mvc

I have below code for the register form and when user inputs their data and hits enter, the RegisterFunction should fire but in the below case its not happening instead of clicking manually on the anchor tag. Any idea?

```
    <form id="Register">
     <a class="btn green pull-right" data-bind="click: RegisterFunction"> Login</a>
    </form>

RegisterFunction : function () {
//logic goes here 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="Register">
     <a class="btn green pull-right" data-bind="event: { keypress: RegisterFunction }"> Login</a>
    </form>

RegisterFunction : function (data, event) {
              var evt = event;
               if (window.event != undefined) { evt = window.event };
              var keycode = (event.which) ? event.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 13) { //13 is key cod for enter key
           //call your function here  
           MyFunctionCall();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout also have offered a `submit binding` - [read more about submit binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html)

```
<form id="Register" data-bind="submit: RegisterFunction">
    <a class="btn green pull-right" data-bind="click: RegisterFunction"> Login</a>
</form>

RegisterFunction : function () {
//logic goes here 
}
```